# How to find network traffic in Multi DC cassandra environment?

Tags: cassandra, opscenter, network-traffic

We have the application in Multi DC environment and would like to know the network traffic when the 2 DCs talk each other [while replicating the data, during consistency etc ] Do we have any command in nodetool to know or from Opscenter graphs which gives the exact value? From Opscenter, I see

```
OS:Net Sent 
OS:Net Received metrics.
```

Is that how we know the traffic?

```
DC1 : US
DC2 : Asia
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try the command **nodetool netstats**, it will print out all current network traffic between the **connected** node and all other nodes. To my knowledge there is no command to display global inter-DC traffic